# How to handle lots of missing values in GradientBoostingClassifier in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

All features are in float data type, whereas there are some features with dominant amount of NaN. I tried to train model via `GradientBoostingClassifier` as below.

```
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(features[feature_headers], features[target_header], test_size=0.33, random_state=int(time.time()))
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=int(time.time()), learning_rate=0.1, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1, n_estimators=300, min_samples_split=2, max_features=None)
clf.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

But error will be thrown:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

I couldn't use some Imputation methods to fill in the NaN with either mean, median or most_frequent since it doesn't make any sense from the data's perspective. Is there any better way to make classifier recognize NaN and treat it as a indicative feature as well? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can't you replace the NaNs with zeros? Your answer is pretty context specific given most of the time people will impute missing NaN values.

Comment: all columns are in float format, and they may range from [negative_value, positive_value], so it means there's possibility that the real value would be 0, so if I fill the NaN with 0, would it be a issue? Thanks! @jonnybazookatone

Comment: As @Harry_pb notes, it should be fine, specifically for GBC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to perform data cleaning. For that, you need to see which all `columns` you are going to include in the training dataset. For float, you may replace all `null` values with zero

```
df.col1 = df.col1.fillna(0)
```

and for strings, you may replace it the default value.

```
df.col2 = df.DISTANCE_GROUP.fillna('')
```

Now, if you want to place `average` or some trend value, you may use the same learned algorithm to predict missing values and fill up. For running the algorithm, first replace null values and then later can be altered with more accurate predicted values.

> Note: Any learning algorithm can't run with null values.

Comment: all columns are in float format, and they may range from [negative_value, positive_value], so it means there's possibility that the real value would be 0, so if I fill the NaN with 0, would it be a issue? Thanks!

Comment: @JasonZhu I personally use 0 as I mentioned in answer that we can later predict the same value using learning algorithm, but to run the algorithm, we need to replace null values. I prefer 0 as it doesn't affect much the orientation of learned values.

Comment: I see. Thanks! BTW, I have a categorical column with values of ('A', 'B', None), I've encoded it to (1, 2, 0). Should I do in this way or just leave it in string format for GradientBoostingClassifier to train on the model? Which one would be better?

Comment: Your encoding or OneHotEncoding.

Comment: @JasonZhu I am not so sure about your dataset, but as Jonny mentioned (I didn't knew this term btw.), I used encoding that worked quite well for me where length of data was pretty small (20k rows) but I am not sure if this will work for you as well.

Comment: OK, thanks both guys! @jonnybazookatone and Harry_pb

Answer (score 3):

`xgboost.XGBClassifier` handle `np.nan` without imputation [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235489/xgboost-can-handle-missing-data-in-the-forecasting-phase).

`xgboost` has a `sklearn` api easy to use [look at the documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn).

`xgboost.XGBClassifier` is fundamentally very close form `GradientBoostingClassifier`,  both are Gradient Boosting methods for classification. See for exemple [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282459/xgboost-vs-python-sklearn-gradient-boosted-trees).